# Jest tests with Angular 16 fail to find variables.scss

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have added Angular's experimental support for Jest to an existing project (@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest).

When I run npm test. The project builds as expected but then the tests fail with the following error.
`✘ [ERROR] Can't find stylesheet to import. ╷ 1 │ @import "_variables.scss";`

I have tried to add stylePreprocessorOptions as suggested by other SO articles but this option only seems to be available when using the Jasmine builder.

```
       "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": [
            "src/shared"
          ]
        },
```

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?  If so, how have they managed to solve it?

Currently, my test section in the angular json looks like:

```
        "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",
      "options": {
        "polyfills": [
          "zone.js",
          "zone.js/testing"
        ],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json"
      }
    },
```

My devDependencies are:

```
  "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.11",
"@angular/cli": "~16.2.11",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.12",
"@testing-library/angular": "^14.3.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
"@types/jest": "^29.5.7",
"@types/node": "^20.9.0",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
"json-loader": "^0.5.7",
"typescript": "~5.1.3"
```

}

And my script to run the tests is

```
    "test": "ng test",
```